# Логирование uvicorn

Tags: python, python-3.x, uvicorn

Как логировать записи в файл, в uvicorn? По умолчанию, всё логируется в stdout, stderr.

Есть описание конфигов в `uvicorn.config`:

```
LOGGING_CONFIG = {
    "version": 1,
    "disable_existing_loggers": False,
    "formatters": {
        "default": {
            "()": "uvicorn.logging.DefaultFormatter",
            "fmt": "%(levelprefix)s %(message)s",
            "use_colors": None,
        },
        "access": {
            "()": "uvicorn.logging.AccessFormatter",
            "fmt": '%(levelprefix)s %(client_addr)s - "%(request_line)s" %(status_code)s',  # noqa: E501
        },
    },
    "handlers": {
        "default": {
            "formatter": "default",
            "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
            "stream": "ext://sys.stderr",
        },
        "access": {
            "formatter": "access",
            "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
            "stream": "ext://sys.stdout",
        },
    },
    "loggers": {
        "uvicorn": {"handlers": ["default"], "level": "INFO"},
        "uvicorn.error": {"level": "INFO"},
        "uvicorn.access": {"handlers": ["access"], "level": "INFO", "propagate": False},
    },
}
```

Но как им пользоваться, я не очень понял. Особенно, если я хочу использовать [loguru](https://github.com/Delgan/loguru), например.

Следует отметить, что в потрохах `uvicorn`, есть класс, переопределив который, можно переопределить и сам способ вывода:

`uvicorn.protocols.http.httptools_impl:HttpToolsProtocol`, внутри которого инициализируется: `RequestResponseCycle`. Здесь же, возможно, будет полезным убрать `raises`, чтобы портянки логов было удобно собирать. Но всё это выглядит оверхедом и должен быть более простой способ

Comment: https://www.uvicorn.org/settings/#logging и пишем конфиг-файл в соответствии с документацией питона https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#an-example-dictionary-based-configuration

Comment: (хотя лично я не парился бы и просто загнал всё в systemd, который автоматически запишет всё в свой journald)

Comment: А названия логгеров uvicorn, наверное, можно в исходниках подглядеть https://github.com/encode/uvicorn/blob/5acaee5b9ef477c8210b0d7b5a9c88ad11d217d0/uvicorn/config.py#L282-L284

Comment: @andreymal подскажите, что конкретно прописать в конфиге?